# How to export a date range in Calendar

Tags: calendar, ical

I would like to export some of the events in one of my calendars. The export function will create a `.ics` file with the *entire* calendar, but I only want to export events within a specified date range. How can I do that?

Comment: I can offer you an obvious workaround: create a temporary calendar, copy your events there and export it.

Comment: Sure, but how can I select and copy, say, one year worth of events?

Comment: Select month view and copy all 12 months (unfortunately you can't copy/paste in year view). I know, not ideal, just a workaround, as said above...

Comment: Thanks, it's not ideal, but it works. You might want to post that as an answer. I'll be glad to accept it if nothing better comes up in the following couple of days.

Comment: Added, hopefully someone has a better answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround would be:

- Create a temporary calendar from File>New Calendar.
- Mark the calendars you want to export:

  [image]
- Depending on the time range you want to export select week or month view:

  [image]
- Go to the week or month you want to export, press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to select all events and <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to copy them.
- Select the temporary calendar:

  [image]

  and press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> to paste all previously copied events.
- Export the temporary calendar as an ics file:

  [image]
- Delete the temporary calendar with Edit>Delete.

Answer (score 2):

You can at least Drag and Drop single events out of the Calendar window.

Answer (score 1):

Although jaume came up with an very easy workaround somebody might be looking for an even easier solution. Take a look at the [Calex App](http://calexapp.com) which offers a little bit more features. For example Calex lets you export multiple calendars into one single file.